# How to remove the first element of an array in JSONata?

Tags: arrays, element, jsonata

How do I remove the first element of an array that looks like this:

```
{
  "array":[
    {
      "item":"1"
    },
    {
      "item":"2"
    },
    {
      "item":"3"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am expecting it to look like this:

```
{
  "array":[    
    {
      "item":"2"
    },
    {
      "item":"3"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be accomplished via the [`$filter` JSONata function](https://www.stedi.com/docs/mappings/jsonata-functions/higher-order#dollarfilter):

```
{
  "array": $filter(array, function ($v, $i) {
    $i != 0
  })
}
```

try it here: [JSONata playground](https://stedi.link/4WjmHLB)

(edited to nest the output under the `array` key per the example output in the question)

Comment: Thanks! This works great and is easy to understand. I was expecting it to be easier though, I am new to Jsonata.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [filter operator](https://docs.jsonata.org/path-operators#---filter) combined with a [bound positional variable](https://docs.jsonata.org/path-operators#-positional-variable-binding) like this to filter it:

```
{ "array": array#$i[$i>0] }
```

Check it out on the playground: https://stedi.link/5hQYetH

Comment: Thanks! This works great, although not quite as easy for me to understand in the future when I look at it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can your [Array.prototype.shift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)

```js
const obj = {
  "array":[
    {
      "item":"1"
    },
    {
      "item":"2"
    },
    {
      "item":"3"
    }
  ]
};
const firstElement = obj.array.shift();
console.log(obj.array)
```

Comment: This doesn't look like JSONata language (https://jsonata.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
const obj = {
   "array":[
       {
            "item":"1"
        },
        {
            "item":"2"
        },
        {
            "item":"3"
         }]}
 
obj.array = obj.array.filter((item , index) => index !== 0);

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use destructuring syntax with spread operator `...`. The first "empty" comma element is ignored. The rest of elements are assigned to `newArray`

```js
const data = {
  "array":[
    {
      "item":"1"
    },
    {
      "item":"2"
    },
    {
      "item":"3"
    }
  ]
};

const { array: [, ...newArray] } = data;

console.log(newArray);
```